# sql loader control file has FIELDS TERMINATED BY ¶ (Pilcrow)

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

I have to load data through sql loader in oracle database. In control file 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY `¶` mention. sql loader unable to recognize pilcrow as a delimiter.

data like

```
HDR¶name¶Id
BDY¶rohan¶2
TRL¶1
```

Comment: so change the delimiter?

Comment: can not change. do you have any idea about charset for pilcrow

Comment: nope and I honestly can't think of a reason you can't change the delimiter to something that makes sense

Comment: actually, data files generated by another system. which is not in my control.

Comment: you can use tr command or perl  to replace the character with something common such as "|"  and then run sql loader. :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201751/replace-non-printable-characters-in-perl-and-sed

Comment: @user9109204 then use that datafile as input and create your own?

Comment: What exactly does the error from SQL\*Loader say, and how are you specifying it in your control file?

Comment: inserting null in tables because SQL loader not able to recognize delimiter. I don't know which charset will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It may help you.

```
Fields terminated by '¶' optionally enclosed by '"'
```

Demo:
First, i have created one table

```
CREATE TABLE test_table1
(
 ID NUMBER,
 ENAME VARCHAR2(200),
 LNAME VARCHAR2(200)
 );
```

I have created one control file test.ctl

```
OPTIONS ( ROWS=5000)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
BADFILE './test_table1.BAD'
DISCARDFILE './test_table.DSC'
APPEND INTO TABLE test_table1
Fields terminated by '¶' optionally enclosed by '"'
trailing nullcols
(
  ID,
  ENAME,
  LNAME       
)BEGINDATA
1¶A¶B
2¶C¶D
```

Run from command prompt:

```
sqlldr control = 'test.ctl' userid = username/password
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The example given by S_Sauden works for me as well..

Initially start by trying with a Hex Value in the ctl file:

```
Fields terminated by X'C2B6'
```

You can use below query to find hex_value for reference:

```
select rawtohex( utl_raw.cast_to_raw( '¶' ) ) from dual;
```

---

If the above idea doesn't work for you then you can check the encoding of the file which you are trying to upload:

```
 file -i datafile
```

Above command works for `linux` to get the charset [encoding]. You can use that information below in `ctl` file for `sqlldr` :

```
load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile
```

Its important to sync the characterset of DB, File, Loader to make sure you don't lose any data in translation.

Below query gives you information about your Oracle DB environment:

```
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS
```

Also you should make sure that your OS environment has correct NLS_LANG environment variable set. If nothing is set then please do the needful. You can use the reference link below for a full guide on the same.

```
export NLS_LANG=[NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]
For example: American_America.UTF8
```

Reference [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)

Please check link for some understanding & reference on [importance of characterset](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_sql_loader_utf8.html).

Comment: Actually what I have observed in Linux environment ¶   was working fine with control file but in windows Environment, it was not working so I read this  As a reference - > https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=differrent-character-set-and-nls. THen I gave export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8 and in control file characterset WE8ISO8859P1.